# Browser getting refreshed after resuming debugger

Tags: jquery, angularjs, gulp, browser-sync

We are running an AngularJs 1.x application with browserSync and gulp. If we pause at a breakpoint for a few seconds and resume, the browser refreshes the page.

Did anyone know why is it happening?

Comment: Are you pressing F5 to continue / resume?

Answer (score 0):

```
browserSync.init({
    files: ['./**/*'],
    startPath: '/src',
    server: '',
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: 'node_modules/*',
        ignoreInitial: true
    },
    socket: {
        clients: { heartbeatTimeout: 60000 }
    }
});
```

add socket object in your browserSync init.